# Original mean from 2 datasets with error

Tags: estimation

Assuming 1 original datasets, and 2 datasets extract from 1 but with 'unknown error'.
Exemple:

Orinigal dataset = randn(mean,var)

2 dataset = Original dataset + randn(mu,sigma)

3 dataset = Original dataset + randn(mu,sigma)

So the 2 and 3 datasets are correlated with the same unknown error (mu and sigma).

Is it possible to back calculate the original mean and variance ?

Thanks
Bin

Comment: This is strongly related to [latent variable modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable_model) (eg, [factor analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis)). Usually, the original mean & SD are not relevant, or are even unitless; typically a mean of 0 & an SD of 1 are stipulated for convenience.

Comment: Thank you Monica. Although for latent variable modeling, I don't think we can do them with only 2 variables ?

Comment: A minimum of 3 variables per factor is usually recommended for factor analysis.  Some software won't let you proceed w/ only 2, but it can be done.

Answer (score -1):

No unless you know the random seeds when generating 2 and 3.